# SQL - Fill in values between range

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I have a table that looks like the following:

| StatusID | StatusIN | StatusOUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 200 | 290 |
| 21 | 200 | 290 |

And the output I'm looking for is to get the values in between, and fill it out such as:

| StatusID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 201 |
| 20 | 202 |
| 20 | etc. |
| 21 | 201 |

Comment: Hi. "to get the values in between" of what? Your example output is not very clear. It would be more obvious if you'd prepare https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a CTE:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  StatusID int
  ,StatusIn int
  ,StatusOut int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (20, 200, 290), (21, 200, 290)

;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT StatusID, StatusIn, StatusOut
    FROM @t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT StatusID, StatusIn + 1 AS StatusIn, StatusOut
    FROM cte
    WHERE StatusIn + 1 <= StatusOut
)
SELECT StatusID, StatusIn
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Urgh, recursive CTE. Use a [tally table / numbers function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1).